# jQuery Scroll Event Not Working With Section

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to make a simple scrollspy with jQuery Scroll event but it fails. Here is my JavaScript part:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#credit_card").scroll(function(){
     console.log('OK');
   });
 });
</script>
```

And HTML part:

```
<section class="method first-of-group" id="credit_card">
...
</section>
```

As you might have guessed, `console.log` is just for testing. This section is under a div and this div has "content" id. If I change my JavaScript code for "content" id, it is working. It's really weird.

If you want to see it live, please visit [here](https://projects.denizb16.com/document/).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is, you don't scroll in one of your sections at all. You scroll down on the document itself but not on the section, since there is no scroll bar in there.

Comment: When you add this css to your sections, you will see what I mean... ` overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    height: 300px;`

Comment: @GerritLuimstra I got it thank you. Do you have any suggestions to make it work?

Comment: What is it that you want to accomplish?

Comment: If you just want to detect a user scroll event, you can bind it to your `#contents` element.

Comment: I want to add "selected" class to proper sidebar item. If you see [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api) you will understand what I mean. Please visit the URL and scroll down, you will see sidebar will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comments and actually understanding what you mean, this is the solution you are looking for.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#content").scroll(function(){

     // when the user scrolls, we want to detect at what section they currently are. 
     // This can be calculated, by comparing the current window scrolltop to the position and height of the section elements.
    var currentTopOffset = $(document).scrollTop();

     $('section').each(function(){
         var min = $(this).offset().top;
         var max = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
         if(currentTopOffset > min && currentTopOffset < max){
           // current section
           // do something here, like getting a value from an input type hidden with the section name
         }
     });
   });
 });
```

I hope this is what you are looking for, or atleast something to get you started with.